# Jquery Confirm (Library) in a form submit

Tags: jquery, html

I am using Jquery Confirm Library and using like this

```
$('#GoToLead').on('click', function (e) {
                console.log('from on click');
                e.preventDefault();



                $('<input type="hidden" name="StartDate" />').val($('#StartDate').val()).appendTo('#theForm');
                $('<input type="hidden" name="EndDate" />').val($('#EndDate').val()).appendTo('#theForm');
                $('<input type="hidden" name="City" />').val($('#City').val()).appendTo('#theForm');
                $('<input type="hidden" name="AbbrName" />').val($('#AbbrName').val()).appendTo('#theForm');
                $('<input type="hidden" name="ZipCode" />').val($('#ZipCode').val()).appendTo('#theForm');
                $('<input type="hidden" name="FirstName" />').val($('#FirstName').val()).appendTo('#theForm');
                $('<input type="hidden" name="LastName" />').val($('#LastName').val()).appendTo('#theForm');
                $('<input type="hidden" name="EmailAddress" />').val($('#EmailAddress').val()).appendTo('#theForm');
                $('<input type="hidden" name="GroupNumber" />').val($('#GroupNumber').val()).appendTo('#theForm');

                var buttonid = this.id;

                callAssignGroupModal(buttonid);


                //alert("data = " + $('#theForm').serialize());
            });

        });

        function callAssignGroupModal() {

            $("#GoToLead").confirm({
                confirm: function (buttonid) {
                    //var token = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();

                    var buttonclickedId = buttonid;

                    var formData = $('#theForm').val();

                    $("form").submit();
                },

                confirmButton: "Continue",
                confirmButtonClass: "btn-primary",
                cancelButton: "Cancel",
                cancelButtonClass: "btn-default",
                dialogClass: "modal-dialog modal-lg",
                post: false,
                text: "Are you sure you want to assign the Group Number of all these leads?",
                title: "Confirm assign the Group number to leads"

            });
```

I am trying to achieve two things here

1. It takes two clicks to make a confirm and proceed the list to the data.
2. The pop-up box is displayed at bottom of the page.

any help is much appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: could you please show us the complete code? the given JS shows syntax issues in my editor.

Comment: i am new to programming.... what else you need sir ? and what is the error you are getting

Comment: kindly post the HTML code as well. need to check the `#GoToLead` element. the closing brackets don't match. you might want to check on them as well.

Comment: and please report what the actual problem is with your current approach

Comment: public async Task<ActionResult> GoToLead (LeadFilter model)
        {
           Evrything is working fine her. thats taking the input and inserting to database
}